# Is fastlane capable of publishing to Mac App Store

Tags: macos, fastlane, mac-app-store

We're trying to automate the release of our app to the Mac App Store. I've been trying to achieve this using `fastlane`. I managed to get this tool working for submitting the apps' metadata (release notes, screenshots etc). 
I can also build the app using the `gym` module, however this results in a .app and not in a .pkg that is needed for submission to the App Store. Even when I use

```
export_method: "package"
```

I cannot imagine I'm the only one trying to achieve this, but I cannot find an answer if it is possible at all. And if possible, how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I have a (old) work in progress PR made for this - https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/pull/12195. Majority of our users are mobile so it has been hard for me to get testing on this :). If you'd like to comment on that PR I would be happy to revive it and work with you on making this work for you!

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will have a look at it!